# tomcat-7/conf files are exposed

Tags: security, tomcat7

I can see all the files like server.xml, context.xml etc. inside tomcat-7/conf/ are visible via url

like http://domain/conf/server.xml , this is accebile, similarly all the files.

Where is this setting to block this

Answer (score 0):

That looks like someone has set the `appBase` for the default `Host` element to be `""` rather than the default `"webapps"`. That is a bad idea on so many different levels.